# Can't add WireGuard VPN connection to Ubuntu Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, vpn, wireguard

I'm having trouble adding a WireGuard VPN connection to the Network Manager on Ubuntu. I've followed several online tutorials and tried different methods, but nothing seems to work.

I've installed WireGuard using the sudo apt install wireguard
command and created the configuration file /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
. The VPN connection works fine when I start it using the sudo wg-quick up wg0
command, but I can't seem to add it to the Network Manager.

When I go to "Add VPN Connection" in the Network Manager, I only see options for OpenVPN and PPTP. There's also an option to "Import from file", but when I select my wg0.conf
file, it says that the file format is not supported.

I've tried restarting the Network Manager with sudo service network-manager restart
, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

### Install wireguard

`$ sudo apt install wireguard`

### Create a Cryptographic Key Pair

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /etc/wireguard
# umask 077
# wg genkey | tee /etc/wireguard/privatekey | wg pubkey | tee /etc/wireguard/publickey
```

### Add Client Public Key to WireGuard VPN Server

```
# wg set wg0 peer <client-public-key> allowed-ips <client-VPN-address>
```

### Create a Network Connection with NetworkManager's Connection Editor GUI Heading

Using `nm-connection-editor`'s GUI as described [here](https://xmodulo.com/wireguard-vpn-network-manager-gui.html).

Comment: Create a Network Connection with NetworkManager's Connection Editor GUI Heading

Assume you are able to do that...

Thats what I am trying to understand how to do. I can't find anywhere that I can add it to the VPN list.

Comment: https://www.xmodulo.com/wireguard-vpn-network-manager-gui.html

Comment: ... and support for **GNOME Settings (Network Panel)** is probably going to come in Ubuntu 23.04: https://9to5linux.com/gnome-44-beta-released-with-quick-settings-enhancements-wireguard-support

Comment: You can clone and build `network-manager-wireguard` manually for 22.04: https://peerchemist.medium.com/how-to-setup-wireguard-vpn-on-ubuntu-server-22-04-c329434aed12